# C# build failed because of .r86 in <filename>csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt

Tags: c#, svn

Seems to be a problem that randomly reappears with no reliability. You can see an example of what this looks like in someone else's code here: https://code.google.com/p/xdpm-toan4/source/browse/trunk/project/GUI/DAO/obj/Debug/DAO.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt?r=115

A little more info: Project is linked to SVN repo where `<<<<<<< .mine` would appear in a fresh pull where it did not exist when committed (all of our programmers in the dept. have experienced this). There is never a "theirs" section however those issues would appear in only SVN files. The `>>>>>>> .r86` appeared in `<filename>csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt` after blowing away the .svn folder. Deleting the `>>>>>>> .r86` line allows the website to build but without knowing more of what is causing this, I'm hesitant to commit and publish my code.

What might be causing this?

Comment: this comes from some kind of merging issue. what exactly were you doing?

Comment: In my specific case, I had no local copy and so used Visual SVN to pull down a copy and immediately built with no issue. I added two lines of code, got the .mine issue. After realizing that .mine was only in svn files and these files were preventing a build, I blew away the svn connection, built, debugged, changed one of the lines of code and got the .r86 issue.

Comment: Do not include the obj directory in source control - it contains intermediate files that can and will be recreated with each build.

Comment: I'll get us to stop doing that because good advice. However, is this going to stop this issue from appearing in the svn files as well?

Comment: There are a ridiculous amount of copies of the same file in that list.  Of course you are having problems, nobody can keep them all the same.

Comment: That's not our code. It's just an example I found that has the same .mine and .r86 lines while trying to find an answer to the problem.